# TypeError on zipping and application of a list of functions and corresponding arguments

Tags: python, function, arguments, list-comprehension

### The problem:

Let `f1`, `f2` be two functions of `x` and a different number of other arguments; what they actually do is irrelevant, but I'll use delta functions for illustration:

```py
def f1(x, p1, p2, v):
    if   x == p1:
        return v
    elif x == p2:
        return v
    else:
        return 0

def f2(x, p1, v):
    if   x == p1:
        return v
    else:
        return 0
```

I now want to construct a function that returns a list of functions of `x` that are sums of the two functions in various combinations:

```py
import itertools
def choice_matrix(n):
    return itertools.product(*[range(n)]*n)

def f(fn1, fn2, n):
    aux1 = [[fn1 if ae == 0 else fn2 for ae in ar] for ar in choice_matrix(n)]
    aux2 = [
        lambda x, args: sum(
            [fn(x, *arg) for fn, arg in zip(fns, args)]
        ) for fns in aux1
    ]
    return aux2
```

where `choice_matrix` is just a function that returns the various combinations of two elements for `n` positions:

```py
>>> cm = list(choice_matrix(2))
>>> for i in range(len(cm)): print(cm)
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(1, 0)
(1, 1)
```

By printing from the function I can see that `aux1` works as intended and does indeed return a matrix of functions:

```py
[<function f1 at 0x7efbdec08730>, <function f1 at 0x7efbdec08730>]
[<function f1 at 0x7efbdec08730>, <function f2 at 0x7efbdec087b8>]
[<function f2 at 0x7efbdec087b8>, <function f1 at 0x7efbdec08730>]
[<function f2 at 0x7efbdec087b8>, <function f2 at 0x7efbdec087b8>]
```

I now try, as a test, to print the second function of the returned list (so `f1 + f2`) with some parameters:

```py
vs = [(1., 2., 3.), (4., 5.)]

test0 = f(f1, f2, 2)

test = test0[1]
print(test(1., vs))
```

`f1` has 4 arguments, `f2` has 3, all appears to be well and this code should, by any logic, return `3.0`. What I get, however, is a `TypeError`; the function takes less positional arguments than it is given:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 323, in <module>
    print(test(1., vs))
  File "test.py", line 283, in <lambda>
    arg in zip(aux1[i], args)])
  File "test.py", line 283, in <listcomp>
    arg in zip(aux1[i], args)])
TypeError: f2() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

### What I tried thus far:

- A similar list comprehension:

```py
def f(fn1, fn2, n):
    aux1 = [[fn1 if ae == 0 else fn2 for ae in ar] for ar in choice_matrix(n)]
    for i in range(len(aux1)): print(aux1[i])
    aux2 = [
        lambda x, args: list(
            map(
                lambda fn, arg: fn(x, *arg), fns, args
            )
        ) for fns in aux1
    ]
    return aux2
```

This gives the same result.

- A complete deconstruction of `aux2` to its base component actions to see what goes wrong:

```py
def f(fn1, fn2, n):
    aux1 = [[fn1 if ae == 0 else fn2 for ae in ar] for ar in choice_matrix(n)]
    aux2 = {}
    for i in range(len(aux1)):
        print(i)
        print(aux1[i])
        print(set(zip(aux1[i], vs)))
        aux2[i] = lambda x, args: sum([fn(x, *arg) for fn, 
                                       arg in zip(aux1[i], args)])
        if i == 1: fun = aux2[i]; print(fun(1., vs))
        print('')
    return aux2
```

Surprisingly enough *nothing* seems to be going wrong. This is the output of all those `print`s for `i = 1`:

```py
1
[<function f1 at 0x7efbdef23730>, <function f2 at 0x7efbdef237b8>]
{(<function f2 at 0x7efbdef237b8>, (4.0, 5.0)), (<function f1 at 0x7efbdef23730>, (1.0, 2.0, 3.0))}
3.0
```

so the functions and their arguments are lined up to be zipped correctly, *are* zipped correctly, are applied correctly and return the expected value, but I still get the same exact `TypeError` so it appears that zipping breaks as soon as the arguments are passed outside the function.

- A pseudofunctional rewrite that avoids zipping:

```py
def f(fn1, fn2, n):
    aux1 = [[fn1 if ae == 0 else fn2 for ae in ar] for ar in choice_matrix(n)]
    def a(fns, x, args):
        if len(fns) == 0 or len(args) == 0:
            return []
        else:
            fhead, *ftail = fns
            ahead, *atail = args
            return [fhead(x, *ahead)] + a(ftail, x, atail)
    for i in range(len(aux1)):
        print('i =', i)
        print(aux1[i])
        if i == 1: print(a(aux1[i], 1., vs)); print(sum(a(aux1[i], 1., vs)))
        print('')
    aux2 = [lambda x, args: a(fs, x, args) for fs in aux1]
    return aux2
```

The internal printouts are giving expected results:

```py
i = 1
[<function f1 at 0x7efbdec19730>, <function f2 at 0x7efbdec197b8>]
[3.0, 0]
3.0
```

and yet the `TypeError` persists.

I'm at my wits' end here. What have I done wrong and how can I make this code function properly? Is there a more robust and/or elegant way of doing this?

Comment: how do you expect to get 3 argumets for `f1()` and 2 arguments for `f2()` from the same comprehension: `[(x,) + arg for arg in args]` ??

Comment: @lenik I don't. I expect to get 4 for `f1` and 3 for `f2`, and I do, as you can see on the third line of the last code block

Comment: then why this error happens? "f2() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given" ?

Comment: @lenik that's what my question's about! You can see clearly in the last code block that this one comprehension returns exactly what I want for both functions, so I'm not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: perhaps, what you see in the last code block and what python sees in the same block are two different things. and python is trying to tell you about that in the error message. you may continue thinking you're right, but I'd recommend to load a debugger and see what is actually going on there.

Comment: Maybe you should write the four functions by hand first, and then see which parts can be generalized, and how.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I understand what you mean and it is sound advice, but I have already done that to no avail, and I'm not really good enough to rewrite this in a purely functional style. I've edited the question to demonstrate my best efforts at this.

Comment: I added an implementation of `choice_matrix` to make this example. *This you should always strive to do: make it easy for someone to copy and paste then reproduce the error*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, thank you. I should've added that, admittedly, but my version was really quite lengthy and embarrassing so it was omitted out of shame. Also I suppose I should edit the question title, since this is a common issue as you pointed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common error. Python uses lexical scoping closures, so inside your nested list comprehension, your lambda captures `fn` as the local variable from the outer list comprehension:

```
aux2 = [lambda x, args: sum(
        [fn(x, *arg) for fn, arg in zip(fns, args)]
        ) for fns in aux1]
```

This variable `fns`.

But by the time the `lambda` is evaluated will you've already finished iterating over `aux1`, so `fns` refers to the *last* value yielded by `aux1` for all your lambdas.

You must take care of creating closures in a loop. The fix is simple, creating another enclosing scope:

```
def f(fn1, fn2, n):
    aux1 = [[fn1 if ae == 0 else fn2 for ae in ar] for ar in choice_matrix(n)]
    aux2 = [(lambda _fns: lambda x, args: sum(
                [fn(x, *arg) for fn, arg in zip(_fns, args)]
                ))(fns)
                for fns in aux1]
    return aux2
```

I urge you not to be so terse, the python style is relative verbose for anyone used to, say, Haskell. Also, note, the argument to `sum` can be a generator expression, so as not to materialize a whole list before passing it to `sum` like you necessitate with a list comprehension (it is evaluated eagerly):

```
    aux2 = [
        (lambda _fns: lambda x, args: 
            sum( fn(x, *arg) for fn, arg in zip(_fns, args) )
        )(fns)
        for fns in aux1
    ]
```